# Java- Issue with opening and Scanning file

Tags: java, bufferedreader, inputstreamreader

I am writing a program in Java, it scans a file, counts lines, character, palindromes, words. My problem is when I ask for a filename, I am using BufferedReader and InputStreamReader to scan the file the user provided, and print the results in another file, my program compiles, when I type in the name of the file nothing happens, program does not finish, and remains stuck, here is code the BufferedReader, if the entire code is needed i will post it up

```
System.out.println("Enter the name of the file you would like to scan: ");
                        String fileName = scan.nextLine();

                        File file = new File(fileName);



          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(System.in));
```

Comment: You´re reading from System.in ... so you´re reading not from file but from System input.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
```

actually you are specifying your reader `InputStreamReader` to read from System as `System.in` though you are trying to read a file. So you have to use `FileReader`. See [How to read file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/best-way-to-read-a-text-file)

also thanks to @user1009560 you can use

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
```

Comment: BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));

Comment: I tried this i am getting: unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

Comment: `FileNotFoundException` is a [checked exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747155/why-am-i-getting-must-be-caught-or-declared-to-be-thrown-on-my-program).

Comment: I handled this, but when I compile it is saying cannot find symbols for filename. what should be in the try block? i have this: try{System.out.println("Enter the name of the file you would like to scan: ");
String fileName = scan.nextLine();
File file = new File(fileName);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
}

Comment: Ask a different question. There is no meaning of answering your query in comments. This is not a forum.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String fileName = scanner.next();
    scanner.nextLine();

    FileReader file = new FileReader(fileName);

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(FileReader);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're creating an InputStreamReader object as System.in as the inputStream property. You'll need to specify a FileInputStream for as the InputStream.